# code out of runnable is executed inside

Tags: android

What I want to achieve here is set a view to visible and let it stay for 3 seconds and then fade away. I do this by timer, handler and runnable. Following is my code:

```
mIntroLayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

final Runnable animationRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mIntroLayer.startAnimation(mFadeAwayAnimation);
    }
};
final Handler animationHandler = new Handler();

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        animationHandler.post(animationRunnable);
    }
}, 3 * 1000);

mIntroLayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

However, what's happening is the intro layer is invisible for 3 seconds then show up and fade away. It seems like the mIntroLayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) statement is executed inside the runnable. Does any one know why is this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your code is really doing right now:

```
mIntroLayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//... schedule the animation
mIntroLayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

You should be setting the view to be invisible **after** the animation ends by using something like:

```
mFadeAwayAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        mIntroLayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

Comment: Thanks, this does solve my problem. I have one more question here. Doesn't handler run the runnable in UI thread? How come mIntroLayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) is not blocked?

Comment: Your Runnable is scheduled to run 3 seconds later. The schedule() call does not block and instead the line after is immediately executed.

Comment: Another way to solve your problem here is to include the 3 seconds of visibility as a part of your animation and then set the animation listener to make sure it stays invisible at the end. This way, you don't need to schedule anything explicitly.